# Display data in 2 tables in one crytal report in c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to display some data on crystal report. after written the code the issued part of the report displayed well while the receiving part displayed only the first data within the range selected and duplicated several times. here is the code below

```
public DataSet itembincardreport(string date1, string date2, string 
itemcode)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = null;
        Connection cs = new Connection();
        con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBcon);
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        frmReport frm = new frmReport();


        string sql = "select * from ISSUED, RECEIVED WHERE 
 ISSUED.ITEMCODE=RECEIVED.ITEMCODE AND ISSUED.ITEMCODE = '" + itemcode + "' 
        AND RECEIVED.ITEMCODE = '" + itemcode + "' and ISSUED.TRANSDATE 
between '" + Convert.ToDateTime(date1) + "' and '" + 
Convert.ToDateTime(date2) + "' and RECEIVED.TRANSDATE between '" + 
Convert.ToDateTime(date1) + "' and '" + Convert.ToDateTime(date2) + "'";

        SqlDataAdapter dadbt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, mycon.DBcon);
        dadbt.Fill(ds);
        dadbt.Dispose();
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: here is the screen shot that i got  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zOk7.jpg

Comment: And what do you get if you run the SQL in a query tool? Same duplication of rows?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is the query. Whether the received and issued tables have multiple rows that match each other or not, I cannot say (you need to post some better example table data than the screenshot given) but your query in the string should be written like this:

```
string sql = 
  @"select * 
    from 
      ISSUED
      inner join
      RECEIVED
      on 
        ISSUED.ITEMCODE=RECEIVED.ITEMCODE -- this is probably the fault 
                                          -- try joining on ISSUEDID = RECEIVED instead??
    where
      ISSUED.ITEMCODE = @itemcode and
      ISSUED.TRANSDATE between @date1 and @date2 and
      RECEIVED.TRANSDATE between @date1 and @date2";
```

Later in your code, you should call:

```
var c = new SqlCommand();
c.CommandText = sql;
c.Connection mycon;
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", itemcode);
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", Convert.ToDateTime(date1)); //you should make the method argument a DateTime
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", Convert.ToDateTime(date2)); //you should make the method argument a DateTime

SqlDataAdapter dadbt = new SqlDataAdapter(c);
```

That's how to PROPERLY do database queries with parameters.. Now whether there are duplicate rows or not is purely down to your table data*, but at least your SQL is immune from hackers putting an itemcode of `'; DROP table issued; --` in and screwing up your world

*post some detailed example data if you want help with that and I'll edit this answer. Take a look at SQLFiddle.com

Comment: do u mean i should write the query like this

Comment: That's how you should always write all your SQL queries in your c# program. This is bad: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '" + myvariable +"'"` . This is good: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = @searchParameter`. For more info google `parameterized queries`

Comment: i need to chat you up or send you mail... here is my email id jinaduadeniyi@yahoo.com pls send me mail, i need to get intouch with you because am still finding it difficult to excute the query

Comment: if you post the problem up onto here though, then you'll get other people chipping in with help.. I do sleep at some point!